# Layer mask to bounds and clips to bounds shows a extra border colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi I need to add border colour and border width to a label which have a corner radious the following is my code

```
_lbl_trans_TKT.clipsToBounds = YES;
_lbl_trans_TKT.layer.cornerRadius = _lbl_trans_TKT.frame.size.width/2;
_lbl_trans_TKT.layer.borderWidth = 8.0f;
_lbl_trans_TKT.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

The following is my out put
[image]

In this after the white border colour I get a little green border which I don't need

Comment: is this happening on device or simulator ?

Comment: This happened in device @TejaNandamuri